# PowerShell Script To Remove Text In File A From File B

Tags: powershell, css-selectors

It seems it is forbidden to create applications that find unused CSS selectors and actually delete them, all they do is find them and create a list (Dust-Me Selectors add-on). The program I used (Skybound Stylizer) doesn't run anymore since I moved to x64.

I want to take the CSV file created by Dust-Me Selectors and delete every line in that file from a CSS file.

It may be necessary to format the CSV file if the data format doesn't agree with the CSS file, but for the sake of this question you can think of each line in the CSV file as a text string.

Dust-Me Selectors sample .csv file:

[Screenshot 1](http://i52.tinypic.com/ege9w8.jpg)

[Screenshot 2](http://i56.tinypic.com/w7lfmx.jpg)

[File](http://www.mediafire.com/?6pydtk1zgrhg86k)

Comment: What about working it backwards by just creating a new file that only has the used rules in it?  I'm somewhat surprised that you can't do this though, so you mean that dust-me doesn't support editing a file in place?

Comment: Have read many times that DMS (and others) does it, but found no way to do it. There's a website that does it for a fee and the author confirmed DMS (and others) doesn't delete the unused selectors.

Comment: Not being familiar with the CSV output from Dust-Me, could you amend the question to show a sample the data? It would be fairly easy if we can assume the CSS in file A is all on a single line but if we have to parse the content, then it *probably* becomes a much more complex problem.

Comment: I want to reduce the size of ".css" files before saving on-line articles as ".mht" files, so I don't mind if the result is far from perfect (if it doesn't change the way the page looks).

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting a line by line match between the CSV file and the CSS file something like this should work: (Note I did this off the cuff more or less from what I have had to do with similar files, but I don't have the script with me at the moment to check)

```
$a1 = (Get-Content .\File1.csv)
$b1 = (Get-Content .\File2.css)

Foreach ($line in $a1)
{
   $b1 | where { $_ -ne $line } | Set-Content .\File3.css
}

Move-Item .\File3.css .\File2.css -Force
```

If it is not a line for line match then change the where statement to be something like:

```
where { $_ -notlike "*$line*"}
```

Comment: Have file A.csv (cat|dog) and file B.css (dog|fish|cat|bird). After running the script file B.txt contents are: fish|cat|bird. It failed to remove line "cat" with both "where {}".

Comment: interesting...I see the same problem, no matter which way I try it. If I switch around the order of A.csv "cat" gets taken out but then "dog" is still there.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about this one...I seem to be missing the logic on this one as to why it is doing this. Another option may be to use Compare-Object but I'm not sure how to use that to create the b.txt. Compare-Object $b1 $a1 | Select InputObject, will give you only the items in $b1 that aren't in $a1.